# Excel formula help (formula to return a value in a row based on characters on a different row)

Tags: excel, function, excel-formula

I have a Google spreadsheet. One of the columns in the spreadsheet is "Subject". It contains rows like - "15 placebo St", "5 Guatemala Ave", "I am really Interested", "Testing", "Rental or Rent".

I wanna make a column besides this "Subject" column called "tags". The tag would be "buyer" or "false". I want to write an if statement that checks the following condition:
#If a row contains an address (has a number somewhere in the cell and/or has the word "St", "Street", "Ave") OR if the subject line has the word "interested" then tag it as a "Buyer". Else "False"

How do I put this as one excel formula?

Comment: Please read [How to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). I read your question to essentially be: *Can someone do my job because I'm too lazy to look up how to write an if-statement excel.*

Comment: thanks for sharing the link on how to ask a question here.
I had tried some formulas and they didn't work 100% for all 17000 rows. I should had been more clear in my question above on what all I had tried with the results.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like you are wanting to know how to keep it all straight in your head!

1. Don't even try.
2. Consolidate.

Step 1: Don't try to be clever and do it all in one column.

- Create one column per test criterion that returns 0 if that row doesn't meet the criteria, and 1 if it does.
- Then, create yet another column that is the `SUM()` of your criterion columns. This gives you a score.
- *Then*, if column W is that score, X2's formula can be `=IF(W2=0, FALSE, "Buyer")` and apply that formula for all of column X.

Step 2: Okay, so now you have your answer by breaking it into several steps, and you can hide those criterion columns. I usually move all the columns I want to hide to the right, so I have a continuous block of visible columns, followed by all the hidden columns. **But if you still want to figure out how to do it all in a *single* column,** it shouldn't be out of reach now that you've broken down and tested all your smaller steps! Now you just have to put it all together. Just be sure to do it in Yet Another Column. That way your work in step one can serve to verify you did it right before you delete all those columns you made in step 1.

But I recommend stopping after step 1, because what you want is wrong.  You're going to get exactly what you want, celebrate, start using it, then realize you should change it or improve it somehow! Keeping it all broken down into several separate steps will be very helpful a month from now when you're trying to figure out what you did so you can change it. Consolidating it will feel the same as... a professor trying to grade papers and coming across a paper written as one big five-page paragraph!!!

Comment: Thank you - I tried this strategy today. I agree with you that it’s better off to consolidate rather than nest and make the job more complicated :)

Comment: Appreciate your time in giving an indepth explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Give a try on below formula-

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"St", "Street", "Ave","interested"},A1)),"Buyer",False)
```

[image]

Comment: I've had tried this formula today but it didn't work 100%.
Subjects like "2543 Nicholas", "125 E Spring Ave" were marked as "False" even though it should have been a "buyer"

Comment: I think I see the problem now. If there is a number, only then the if function will look for words like "St", "Ave". However, it should be to mark it as a "buyer" if there is a number in the row OR words like "St", "Ave", "Interest"...

However, I still don't understand why "testing 123" was marked as a "buyer"

Comment: Try this updated formula- `=SORTN(FLATTEN(INDEX(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"St", "Street", "Ave","interested"},A1)),"Buyer",False))),1,,1,1)`

Comment: Still the same problem mate. Subjects with rows like "11541 Laurel Lk Sq" or "143 Roskeen Ct" are being tagged as "False"

Comment: Although the error rate is marginally lower. I've added more terms like "Dr", "Ct"...
This is great help. Really appreciate your time :)

Comment: Is there a way we can nest another option. If the word ILIKE "%test%" mark it as "False"? Sorry, I'm more well versed with SQL than Excel :)

Comment: Are you on Excel or google-sheet?

Comment: I'm using Google sheet